# DAX: Calculate the ratio of Metric A to a sibling Metric B (when both reside in the same group)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I am a complete *noob* to `DAX` and `OLAP`, so please, forgive any errors.

## Story

Basically, I have a `Matrix` component in `PowerBI Desktop` report. 
**Months** are on the columns, **Metrics** - on the rows:

[image: Excel]

The problem arises when I try to calculate the ratio of (percents in red):

1. **Metric B** to **Metric A** (B/A)
2. **Metric C** to **Metric B** (C/B)

All metrics reside in the same group. I wish these ratios be put as a separate, but **one** column.

I have no problems to calculate **Metric** ratio to total; I just take `SUM(#)` and divide by measure **Total**:

```
Total = CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[#]); ALL('Data'[Metric]))
```

## Question

But how do I get a `SUM(#)` aggregate for **Metric X** *which I could later use to calculate the ratio of other metrics?*

## What I've done so far

As one of the steps I created this table to get the aggregated **#** for **Metric A**:

```
Table = ADDCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZE('Data'; 
                      'Data'[GroupAndMetric];
                      'Data'[Year];
                      'Data'[MonthNo]);
            "Count";
            CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[#]); 'Data'[GroupAndMetric] = "Group A - Metric A")
)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an easier way to get your expected result but I am assuming your data is exactly the same as the posted in the OP.

Create the following measures to calculate the previous and current values in the given context of each metric.

Sum of `[#]`:

```
CurrentValue = SUM(Data[#])
```

Current Group

```
CurrentGroup = FIRSTNONBLANK(Data[Group],0)
```

Current Metric

```
CurrentMetric = FIRSTNONBLANK(Data[Metric],0)
```

Current Month:

```
CurrentMonth = FIRSTNONBLANK(Data[Month],0)
```

This calculates the previous Metric

```
PrevMetric =
IF (
    [CurrentMetric] = "Metric A",
    BLANK (),
    IF (
        [CurrentMetric] = "Metric B",
        "Metric A",
        IF ( [CurrentMetric] = "Metric C", "Metric B", BLANK () )
    )
)
```

Calculate the previous metric sum of # necessary for the ratio calculation:

```
Previous # Sum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Data[#] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Data),
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                Data,
                EARLIER ( Data[Metric] ) = [PrevMetric]
                    && EARLIER ( Data[Group] ) = [CurrentGroup]
                    && EARLIER ( Data[Month] ) = [CurrentMonth]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Finally calculate the ratio:

```
% Ratio = DIVIDE([CurrentValue], [Previous # Sum])
```

You will get a bunch of measures but you just have to use the % Ratio in the matrix:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Am I correct in putting `Previous # Sum` into words like this:

*In `CALCULATE` take column **Data[#]** and `SUM` it on table which is returned by `FILTER`. In that 1st `FILTER` take `ALL` **Data** table despite parent filter context and take only those rows, where each row meets `COUNTROWS` > 0 criteria. 2nd `FILTER` uses the same **Data** table, with the same filter context as applied in the parent `FILTER`. In this 2nd `FILTER` we check whether `EARLIER` row columns, which were filtered by 1st `FILTER` are equal to `PrevMetric`, `CurrentGroup` and `CurrentMonth`.*

Comment: @Gabrielius, You got it!, just be aware that the EARLIER in the inner FILTER serves to filter the those rows in the Group, Metric and Month context getting the right rows to sum up.

Comment: I think I understand. But in which context `PrevMetric`, `CurrentGroup` and `CurrentMonth` work and get evaluated? Are they restricted to `Matrix` contexts defined by `Month`, `Group` and `Metric` columns/rows?

Comment: @Gabrielius In this case yes, because you are specifying that Month, Group and Metric context. If you don't specify any context PrevMetric, CurrentGroup and CurrentMonth measures will be evaluated against the whole dataset (all rows) hence PrevMetric will return the first conditional to become true based on the CurrentMetric value that surely will be `Metric A` (the first row Metric value). CurrentGroup will be the first month in your data and CurrentMonth will be the first month in your data. You can check it by adding a new matrix without any context and use these measures.

Comment: I think, what's difficult for me to understand, is that we have `ALL(Data)` clause, which takes all the data, so I think that `CurrentGroup` and `CurrentMonth` should evaluate against all dataset, which is wrong? So they must evaluate according to `Matrix` context *first*, and only *then* we iterate through all the rows and filter them against those `CurrentMonth` and `CurrentGroup` values? Trying to figure out from where to start to read the query :)

Comment: @Gabrielius, In DAX you should read from inner functions to outer functions. All measures are evaluated against the given context in the matrix so the `Group A` creates a context in the matrix hence when you use `FIRSTNONBLANK(Data[Group],0)` it will evaluated to the first group value in context, i.e `Group A`, and the same for each measure. The only purpose of the measures is to let us filter those rows we need from all rows (`ALL(Data)`). No measures are evaluated against whole Data table in this case. Nice to see you want to break down the expression, that's unusual here :)

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, it was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably (much) better ways of doing this, but here's one way:

To do a metric B divided by metric A (for example):

```
Metric B to Metric A =
DIVIDE (
CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[#] ), FILTER ( Data, Data[Metric] = "Metric B" ) ),
CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[#] ), ALL ( Data[Metric] ), Data[Metric] = "Metric A" ),
BLANK ()
)
```

The first CALCULATE (the numerator) returns blank if the pivot table isn't filtered to metric B. The second CALCULATE (the divisor) returns the sum of Metric A (following any other filters that are applied, so it won't sum up metric B's that are in another group for example, as long as group is on your pivot table). If we're looking at any metric other than B, this whole division will be BLANK because the numerator will be blank. The final BLANK says that if there are no metric A's (i.e. divide by zero), then the result will also be BLANK.

Assuming 2 measures like this, you could then combine them into a single column:

```
Final Ratio =
IF (
NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Metric B to Metric A] ) )
    && NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Metric C to Metric B] ) ),
BLANK (),
IF (
    NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Metric B to Metric A] ) ),
    [Metric B to Metric A],
    IF (
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Metric C to Metric B] ) ),
        [Metric C to Metric B],
        BLANK ()
    )
)
```

)

This first part says, if both measures are not blank, return a blank (i.e. I don't want a group total that doesn't make sense). Then it goes through each metric and says if it isn't blank, display it. Otherwise, display blank. Since each underlying measure only returns a value for a single given metric, this should work.